# Configure MariaDB PAM authentication, and enabling remote login from Toad

Tags: mysql, authentication, mariadb, toad

I am currently trying to integrate Linux services into my Windows environment and have installed MariaDB with PAM authentication following the [guidance from MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pam-authentication-plugin/).

I have tested successfully on the box (using putty) that I can authenticate using my AD credentials, however when I try to login via Toad I get the following error:

```
Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client
```

I have tried adding the line `pam-use-cleartext-plugin` to the conf file and restarting the server but no joy.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve such that remote logins with Toad (and other clients) using AD credentials works?

**Update**

I have downloaded HeidiSQL and confirmed that its use of libmysql.dll means that it can use the PAM authentication.  It looks like toad for MySQL utilises myodbc.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded HeidiSQL and confirmed that its use of libmysql.dll means that it can use the PAM authentication. It looks like toad for MySQL utilises myodbc.dll which cannot handle PAM authentication